# How to find v(infinity)? help please

Tags: steady-state

Can someone help finding V(infinity). Ive gotten V(0+) at 93 V. the second circuit i got is attacked below. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You know what V_inf is.  It says so in the question - it's 0V.  What is asked is how long it takes to get there.

Comment: and it's 1.7mA not 1.7A...

Comment: @ChrisM. Oh right thanks for pointing that out. How would I find the time? would V_c(t) = 0? and then sub V_0 and V_inf, then equate them to find t? What would RC be? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisM.: V_inf is NOT 0V, and the question doesn't say that.

Comment: @DaveTweed You're right, I just caught that.  That's my fault.  It does ask how long to 0V, but V_inf is not going to be 0V due to that current source.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework question, we'll only give you hints, rather than a direct answer.

First hint: Replace the current source and the 40k resistor with its Thevenin equivalent.

Comment: Im not sure how to do that. I have 15 mins left to answer the question. Thanks

Comment: Look up "Thevenin-Norton equivalencies".  The Norton circuit should look familiar

Comment: got it! now can i use nodal analysis to find the voltage across the capacitor?

Comment: So, sitting in an exam room. Isn't this cheating?

Comment: Not necessarily cheating, he could be trying to finish homework before it's due.